# Can amp-bind be used to trigger an amp-story open?

Tags: amp-html

Can the carousel here in link below be built using amp-bind or script?

https://web-player-cards-carousel.web.app/examples/amp-story/player-entry-point-cards.html

The main question is about building it in an amp-valid way

Comment: Yes, but your host page is not AMP nor does it load the relevant libraries.

Comment: Do you have an example or point to docs for how to trigger an amp-story loading from the amp-story-player using bind?

Comment: If the host page is an AMP page and the `amp-bind` library is loaded for that page, then all components on that page may be controllable with `amp-bind`. AFAIK, there is no exception. There are amp-components that may not be included in amp-story. Example: amp-iframe. If your effort fails (following this advice) post the result and I'll take another look. I could be wrong (have been before) but I don't see any documentation that contradicts the above.